# Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, iterator, batch-processing

I am experiencing a problem while training a neuronal network consisting of two convolution layers. I have a bunch of images that I normalize and resize to shape (28,28,3) within an "make iterator" function.

The training phase runs then normally till I encounter this error :

"InvalidArgumentError: Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [28,28,4], [batch]: [28,28,3]
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext_31}}]]"

I first tried to load some images and resize them using opencv and it then worked. However given the size of my dataset I need to use iterators and dataset objects provided by keras util to train my network on all the images I have.

Here is the code for the iterator:

```py
def make_iterator(filenames, labels, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))

    def parse(filename, label):
        image = tf.read_file(filename)
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
        image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
        image = tf.image.resize(image, (28,28))
        image = tf.reshape(image,  [28,28,3])
        image = image / 256
        return {'image': image, 'label': label}

    dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.map_and_batch(
        map_func=parse, batch_size=batch_size, num_parallel_batches=8))

        return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

Here are the details of my Convnet:

```py
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

And last here are the parameters for the fit phase:

```py
history = model.fit(images
                    , labels
                    , epochs=200
                    , steps_per_epoch= len(train_image_labels) // batch_size
                   )
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you ever find an answer?